# VSCode: the focused file in the Open Editors view is being closed instead of the file I'm trying to close

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I'm focused on a file and try to close another file, the focused file is the one being closed.

[image: screencap showing the problem described below]

As you can see, I'm trying to close the file `edit.blade.php` and after pressing the X button the file closed is actually the `DummyService.php`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please follow the [guide about submitting bugs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) (notably: check if it's already been reported; add version info; try reproducing the issue with all extensions disabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported and may be fixed in the next release hopefully.

See [Open Editors pane - closes wrong file when clicking the close icon](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194326)

> This should be fixed in the next release :)

I can reproduce in the current Stable build but NOT in the current Insiders build.  A new Stable should go out early October 2023.

and especially

[Open editors view does not close editor that is selected anymore](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193574)